# How to define DSL query with combinations of AND & OR logic(OR logic inside AND)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'd like to define a DSL query, to describe the query in Lucene below :

```
q = role:(admin OR manager) AND priority:(high OR middle).
```

I know that I can use `should` to indicate the `OR` logic, however, the DSL query below :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "role": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "role": "manager"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "priority": "high"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "priority": "middle"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

can't achieve what I need, since the data

```
{
  "role": [ "admin", "manager"],
  "priority": "low"
}
```

would be considered as valid, but it DOESN'T.

How can I fix my DSL query? I'm using ElasticSearch 5.2.2, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "role": "admin"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "role": "manager"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "priority": "high"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "priority": "middle"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```